# How can I access my couchdb from my node server using REST/JSON/GET/POST?

Tags: json, http, rest, node.js, couchdb

I'm trying to access my couchdb from a node.js server.

I've followed the nodejs tutorial, and have set up this simple nodejs server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

I would like to make RESTful http and POST requests to the nodejs server. The nodejs server should then be able to make GET/POST request to the Couchdb, which responds with JSON objects.

How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a module ([node-couchdb-api](https://github.com/dominicbarnes/node-couchdb-api)) I've written for this exact purpose. It has no ORM or other features like that, it's just a simple wrapper for the HTTP API that CouchDB offers. It even follows the conventions established by Node.JS for async callbacks, making your code that much more consistent all-around. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all I am the author of `nano` and will use it in this response.

Here go some simple instructions to get started with node.js and CouchDb.

```
mkdir test && cd test
npm install nano
npm install express
```

If you have couchdb installed, great. If you don't you will either need to install it setup a instance online at [iriscouch.com](http://iriscouch.com)

Now create a new file called `index.js`. Inside place the following code:

```
var express = require('express')
   , nano    = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984')
   , app     = module.exports = express.createServer()
   , db_name = "my_couch"
   , db      = nano.use(db_name);

app.get("/", function(request,response) {
  nano.db.create(db_name, function (error, body, headers) {
    if(error) { return response.send(error.message, error['status-code']); }
    db.insert({foo: true}, "foo", function (error2, body2, headers2) {
      if(error2) { return response.send(error2.message, error2['status-code']); }
      response.send("Insert ok!", 200);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3333);
console.log("server is running. check expressjs.org for more cool tricks");
```

If you setup a `username` and `password` for your CouchDB you need to include it in the url. In the following line I added `admin:admin@` to the url to exemplify

```
, nano    = require('nano')('http://admin:admin@localhost:5984')
```

The problem with this script is that it tries to create a database every time you do a request. This will fail as soon as you create it for the first time. Ideally you want to remove the create database from the script so it runs forever:

```
var express = require('express')
   , db    = require('nano')('http://localhost:5984/my_couch')
   , app     = module.exports = express.createServer()
   ;

app.get("/", function(request,response) {
    db.get("foo", function (error, body, headers) {
      if(error) { return response.send(error.message, error['status-code']); }
      response.send(body, 200);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3333);
console.log("server is running. check expressjs.org for more cool tricks");
```

You can now either manually create, or even do it programmatically. If you are curious on how you would achieve this you can read this article I wrote a while back [Nano - Minimalistic CouchDB for node.js](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/08/nano-minimalistic-couchdb-client-for-nodejs.html).

For more info refer to [expressjs](http://expressjs.org) and [nano](http://github.com/dscape/nano). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use node.js module such as [Cradle](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle) to work with CouchDB.

Here is a list of available Node.JS modules: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Comment: Cradle is known to be buggy / leak.

Comment: really? give us some links about this

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle/issues/93) I couldn't get `DELETE` requests to work at all with cradle, they work with `request` (sometimes). In general `DELETE` requests to couch are known to be buggy with node. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

Just make HTTP requests. I would recommend [`request`](https://github.com/mikeal/request)

Here's an example [from my code](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/model/auth.js#L88)

```
request({
    "uri": this._base_url + "/" + user._id,
    "json": user,
    "method": "PUT"
}, this._error(cb));
```

Here's another example [from my code](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/model/post.js#L96)

```
// save document
"save": function _save(post, cb) {
    // doc changed so empty it from cache
    delete this._cache[post.id];

    // PUT document in couch
    request({
        "uri": this._base_url + "/" + post._id,
        "json": post,
        "method": "PUT"
    }, this._error(function _savePost(err, res, body) {
        if (body) {
            body.id = post.id;
            body.title = post.title;
        }
        cb(err, res, body);
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you glorious basterd! This worked for me. FSM knows why, but I've really been struggeling to figure this stuff out. Don't know why all the other node extensions haven't worked, but this one did! THANK YOU!